# Who is the top foreigner speaking Korean?

Tags: discussion, chat

Recently, I watch splash english - youtube.

As you know, we can find many foreigns speaking Korean. Someone
speaks fast and uses splendid vocabularies, more than natives.
Further, they have a quickness.

But to me, if I must choose one, then my choice is Josh of splash
english : Pronunciation is very close to that of native [link](https://splashenglish.com/koreans-and-accent/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is that PJ Rogers (김미남) or Robert Holley (하일) are the best foreigners I've ever heard speak Korean.

I could not find a video of PJ Rogers speaking Korean. But he's pretty good I feel.

Robert Holley
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EsiDRyarxw

This guy is also decent. (I know him personally, so I'm biased)
https://www.youtube.com/user/GoBillyKorean/featured

Comment: A very serious note: Ha Il, or Robert Holley, is not a *foreigner*. He is a naturalized citizen of the Republic of Korea, whose only passport is South Korean. Calling him a "foreigner" may sound at least ethno-nationalist, if not racist.

Comment: That's his political affiliation. His origin is the USA. He is not a *native* Korean. He is amazing at Korean. He is a Korean from a political standpoint. But he is a man who is not a native Korean speaker. He learned Korean as an adult.

Comment: Well, the OP asked for a "foreigner", not a "non-native." The OP may also have intended "non-native" when he said "foreigner", but that's a very controversial labelling.

Comment: One can be both from a foreign country (a foreigner) and become a citizen of a new country. And Robert Holley is not a native Korean. As you say, he is a naturalized citizen. This means his nativity in definitively not Korea. Hence he is both a foreigner and a non-native Korean speaker. This is to take nothing away from his exemplary abilities in Korean.